# How does hibernate change a val in a kotlin class?

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, constants

In the following code, how can hibernate change the value of the `val` member `id`?  Even the reference to the object is a `val` so I cannot see how a different object might be being substituted.

```
import jakarta.persistence.*
import java.util.UUID

@Entity
class Bar (val v: Int = 0) {
  @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(columnDefinition="UUID default gen_random_uuid()")
  val id = UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
}

fun main () {
  val emf = HibernatePersistenceProvider().createContainerEntityManagerFactory(
    MyPersistenceUnitInfo(), Properties()
  )
  emf.createEntityManager().let { em ->
    em.transaction.begin()
    val b = Bar(7)
    println(b.id)  // prints 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    em.persist(b)
    println(b.id)  // prints 82a7bc5a-f92d-4d7f-872a-3eb3ba7a5541
    em.transaction.commit()
    em.close()
  }
}
```

I am indeed using the JPA plugin in my `build.gradle.kts` as follows:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "latest.release"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "latest.release"
    id("com.google.cloud.tools.jib") version "latest.release"
    id("com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin") version "latest.release"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version "latest.release"
    application
}
```

But I am not using the "all open" plugin, if that matters.

Finally I'm still confused how `val id` within a `val b` references changes due the `em.persist(b)` call as shown by the two `println`s

Comment: I don't know the answer, but `val` doesn't protect you from Hibernate setting the backing field's value via reflection. I'd assume that's what happens

Comment: @Joffrey I'm a little surprised because I thought `val` in kotlin would translate to `final` in Java on the backing field. However, it seems that reflection can modify `final` values too, so you are probably correct. (the same applies to `private`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you disassemble the compiled class `Bar` with javap you will see that the signature is:

```
public final class foo.Bar {
   private final int v;
   private final java.util.UUID id;
   public foo.Bar(int);
   public foo.Bar(int, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker);
   public final int getV();
   public final java.util.UUID getId();
   public foo.Bar();
}
```

... so your assumptions on the generated class are correct. But `final` fields are not protected from modification with reflection, so Hibernate can change the value of the `id` field anyhow...

If you set a breakpoint in the `java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Object obj, Object value)` method and run your test with the debugger, you will see the call and the access path that Hibernate uses...